# Sqooping same table for different schema in parallal is failing

Tags: sqoop

We are having different data base schemas in Oracle. We are planning to sqoop some of the tables from oracle to Hive ware house. But If we put sqooping of tables of an oltp is sequential it is working. But to have a better usage we are planning to sqoop different oltps tables parallay, but it is faling to sqoop same table parallay.

It seems while sqooping a Table, one temporary table will be created in hdfs by sqoop and from there it will move the data to hive table, because of that reason we are not able to sqoop parallay.

Is there any way that we sqoop same tables parallay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter --target-dir to specify arbitrary temporary directory on HDFS where Sqoop will import data first. This parameter should be working in conjunction with --hive-import.

Comment: We are passing target directory for all the sqoop jobs that we created, but I can see, first it is creating a table in temporary location and from there it is copying the data to target-dir location (it is my understanding only)